# Fade background to black on bottom of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to fade in a DIV using opacity when the user gets close to the bottom of the page.
Let's say the page is 3000px high, i want the fade in to start at 2400px and end up completely faded in when the user hits the bottom.

Here is the function i use on the top, but i cant figure out the math i need to get the oposite effect on the bottom of the page...

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = event => {
      const checkpoint = 500;
      const start = 200;
      let opacity;
      const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      
      if (currentScroll >= start) {
        if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
          opacity = 1 - currentScroll / checkpoint;
        } else {
          opacity = 0;
        }
      } else {
        opacity = 1 - currentScroll / checkpoint;
      }
      document.querySelector(".intro").style.opacity = opacity;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

This is my try. But it does not work.
In short. My theory is to map the difference between the checkpoint variable 2400 and the height variable 3000 to a value between 0.0 and 1. Then assign it to the opacity of the Div. But sadly my head cant figure it out.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = event => {

      let opacity;
      const height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
      const checkpoint = height - 700;
      const currentScroll = window.scrollY;

      // if (currentScroll >= start) {
        if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
          opacity = 0
          console.log('if opacity: ',opacity)
        } else {
          opacity =  currentScroll / checkpoint * 1;
          console.log('else opacity: ',opacity)
        }
      document.querySelector(".footer").style.opacity = opacity;
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

-R

Answer (score 1):

### Please check this code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [currentScroll, setCurrentScroll] = useState(0);

  window.onscroll = function (e) {
    // console.log(window.scrollY);
    setCurrentScroll(window.scrollY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(currentScroll);
    },
    [currentScroll]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      .....
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GSAP ScrollTrigger example.

`ScrollTrigger.create({ trigger: document.body, start: "top top", end: "bottom bottom", // onCallback function });`